# Yii Calling two separate methods and updating two separate fields dependent on one dropdown

Tags: ajax, yii

Okay, so I have a dropdown list which calls a method through AJAX and updates another dropdown list (which works,BTW).

I also have a method to display images taken from the database(works too.)

Now I want said dropdown to also call the method for displaying images everytime the dropdown changes. Any ideas how to do this?

Any push would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do one more ajax-request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(){
    // ajax request for getting image from database
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the info! i solved it, i just called the other method from the first and returned both through an array encoded in json.

thanks btw!